# How do I specify an empty list of ports in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

Is there a way to specify an empty array in docker-compose.yml?

I tried `ports: []` to no avail.

A JSON empty array literal *should* be valid YAML syntax, but when I use this, I get the following error from Docker:

> services.myapp_migrations.ports must be a list

###### For more context:

I have a python application with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  myapp: &myapp
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - MYAPP_DB_HOST=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./.env:/app/.env
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  myapp_migrations:
    <<: *myapp
    command: ["migrate"]
    restart: on-failure
    ports: []

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${MYAPP_DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${MYAPP_DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${MYAPP_DB_NAME}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to re-use the `myapp` definition with a YAML anchor, but I need to override the `ports` definition in `myapp_migrations`.

(I know I could use [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extension-fields) for this, but I'm trying to avoid that.)

Comment: The [compose spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md) has a horribly unspecific wording on this but I believe you should file it as bug since a) the error message is wrong or at least misleading – you *are* giving a list – and b) the compose spec does not contain any wording that forbids this, so the file should be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @flyx this is probably a temporary bug.

You might be able to work around this by using `docker-compose` in place of `docker compose`. Because they are separate binaries, they are updated independently.

For example, given your yaml above:

###### docker compose (not working)

```
test % docker compose config
services.myapp_migrations.ports must be a list
```

###### docker-compose (working)

```
test % docker-compose config
WARNING: The MYAPP_DB_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYAPP_DB_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYAPP_DB_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: /Users/jvanus/test
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      MYAPP_DB_HOST: postgres
    ports:
    - published: 8000
      target: 8000
    volumes:
    - /Users/jvanus/test/.env:/app/.env:rw
    working_dir: /app
  myapp_migrations:
    build:
      context: /Users/jvanus/test
    command:
    - migrate
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      MYAPP_DB_HOST: postgres
    ports: []
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
    - /Users/jvanus/test/.env:/app/.env:rw
    working_dir: /app
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ''
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ''
      POSTGRES_USER: ''
    image: postgres:12-alpine
version: '3.9'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I _am_ using `docker-compose up` and getting the failure message. `docker-compose config` gives me the error message. (Docker Compose version 2.0.0-beta.4 )

Comment: Upgrading to docker-compose `2.0.0-beta.6` worked.

Comment: Ah. Based on https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/ I guess you might have been opted-in to the new v2 beta depending on your OS and configuration. You might be able to opt-out in the experimental features section of the docker desktop GUI or with `docker-compose disable-v2`.